# XML - Use Document methods on a Node

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am doing a lot of XML parsing/transformation using the `org.w3c.dom` classes.

A `Document` object provides a lot of handy methods for traversing a document
that are not available to a `Node` object (e.g. [`getElementsByTagName(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29)).  Quite often I find myself getting `Node` elements and wanting to use the 
convenience methods of `Document` on the child `Node` instances (one node at a time).

Is there any way I can convert a `Node` to a `Document`?

The 
[`Document.adoptNode(Node)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#adoptNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29) 
or
[`Document.importNode(Node,boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean%29)
seems to provide what I want, but I cannot figure how to get an 
instance of a blank `Document` in which to embed the node.  Is there a way to get 
a blank `Document`?

Or am I thinking about/approaching this in an entirely wrong way?

Invitatons to RTFM (pointing to a specific method/class that can clear my 
conundrum) would be welcome, as well as any other thoughts or strategies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a `NodeList`, but every item of the node list is an instance of [`Element`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html). And `Element` also has a `getElementsByTagName()` method.

Just cast the nodes from the node list to `Element`.

Comment: Yes! That seems to be what I was missing.  Thanks very much.  :)